# Whose MGF is $\int_0^\infty M(ut)e^{-u}du$, where $M(t)$ is MGF of random variable $X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose $M(t)$ is Moment generation function (MGF) of random variable $X$, i.e., $M(t):= \mathbb{E}[e^{Xt}]$.

Now $T$ involve $X$ and any other random variables such that $T$ has MGF
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty M(ut)e^{-u}du.
\end{equation}

My problem is that how to describe the probability distribution of $T$?

Comment: It would appear that $e^{t T} =_d M(tU)$ for $U\sim \mathrm{Exp}(1)$, i.e. $T =_d t^{-1}\log M(tU)$

Comment: @Andrew I see. Thank you very much!